Agora Cloud Recording API: 'fileNamePrefix validation failed' error despite correct payload
I'm trying to start a cloud recording using Agora's API, but I'm consistently getting a 'fileNamePrefix validation failed' error. Here's my current setup:
Node.js environment
Agora Cloud Recording API v1
AWS S3 for storage (region: ap-south-1)
Here's the payload I'm sending:
const start_recording_payoad = {
  "uid": user_id.toString(),
  "cname": channel_name,
  "clientRequest": {
    "token": token,
    "recordingConfig": {
      "maxIdleTime": 30,
      "streamTypes": 2,
      "channelType": 0,
      "videoStreamType": 0,
      "transcodingConfig": {
        "height": 720,
        "width": 1280,
        "bitrate": 2000,
        "fps": 30,
        "mixedVideoLayout": 1,
        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
      }
    },
    "recordingFileConfig": {
      "avFileType": ["hls", "mp4"]
    },
    "storageConfig": {
      "accessKey": "xxxxxxxx",
      "region": 9,  // Updated to 9 for ap-south-1
      "bucket": "xxxxxx",
      "secretKey": "SECRET_KEY_HIDDEN",
      "vendor": 2,
      "fileNamePrefix": ["partner_live_stream_recording", `${channel_name}`, `${user_id}`]
    }
  }
};

And here's how I'm making the API call:
const startResponse = await axios.post(`https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/${appId}/cloud_recording/resourceid/${resource_id}/mode/mix/start`, start_recording_payoad, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': authorizationField,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  }
});

The error I'm receiving is:
Error Response Data: { code: 2, reason: 'start: fileNamePrefix validation failed!' }

I've tried several approaches to resolve this issue:

Simplified the fileNamePrefix to a single string: ["partner_live_stream_recording"]
Used different combinations in the fileNamePrefix array, including static strings and dynamic values
Ensured that channel_name and user_id don't contain any special characters
Double-checked all other fields in the payload for correctness
Verified the AWS S3 bucket configuration and accessibility
Confirmed the correct Agora region code for my AWS region (ap-south-1)
Attempted to remove the fileNamePrefix field entirely as a test

I expected the API call to successfully initiate the cloud recording process, creating a new recording session with the specified parameters. The anticipated result was a positive response from the API with details about the started recording session.
Instead, I consistently receive the fileNamePrefix validation error, preventing the recording from starting. I'm unsure what specific aspect of the fileNamePrefix is causing the validation to fail, as the error message doesn't provide detailed information about the nature of the validation failure.

It sounds like the issue you were facing was due to having special characters in the folder name. Once you removed the special characters, the issue was resolved. Here’s a summary of the problem and solution:
Problem:

Original folder structure: fileNamePrefix: ["partner_live_stream_recording", ${channel_name}, ${user_id}]
The underscore character (_) in the folder name caused an issue.

Solution:

Updated folder structure: fileNamePrefix: ["partnerivestreamrecording", ${channel_name}, ${user_id}]
Removing the underscore character fixed the issue.

